# How can I create a shared portal for tenant

Tags: django, django-tenants

I have a question about django-tenent-scheme library.
How may I create a tenant management portal, that is not shared with other tenants?

I want to display a main page where a new customer can create his account and after that new tenant will be created.
For instance, myapp.net/Portal is for creating new customers and for managing accounts, buying licenses, etc.

And after creating a client he gets his own URL client.myapp.net.

Is there any way to create a management portal in the project or should I create another project, deploy it with another server, and manage it by DNS like

myapp.com A --> portal IP

*.myapp.com A --> app ip

I can create a tenant for the portal with the domain myapp.net but the portal is available in all tenants like  client.myapp.net/portal